# Unity NavMesh obstacles are not working with Box shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

My NavMesh Obstacles work only with capsule shapes. If i use box shape, it does not carve a hole in the NavMesh. I need a horizontal box for some obstacles and with capsules i cannot achieve that. I am confused why just changing the shape affects the functionality.

I am using Render Meshes as geometry.

[image]

and box shape for NavMesh obstacle. If i change box to capsule, it works but i cannot use capsules for everything.

[image]

Comment: my box collider works as an obstacle avoidance.. please explain further what you see, how exactly to make a [mcve] , which versions etc

Comment: Please check original post. I edited. I am using render meshes for geometry. Physics collider does not carve a hole in the Navigation surface. Also box shape is not carving a hole. Only capsules are working. Not sure why.

Comment: i did not need to add the modifier, just the obstacle, and it worked after baking

Comment: Ok. not sure. I tried removing the navigation modifier but still no hole when carved and baked.

Comment: well, its hard to be sure given https://imgur.com/a/Sxjo0ck worked perfectly for me. Also worked without carve only when statiionary, nor is it static in any way

Comment: I am using 2D but still. I guess i will just go with an ugly solution and use capsules laid side by side to create a box. Thanks though.

Comment: oh - so its 2d?? see - funny you never mentioned that..  we cant be mind readers

Comment: yes. sorry i missed it.